# What Java List-related subtlety is causing my Heap's Algorithm implementation to fail?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, permutation, heaps-algorithm

I am attempting to implement "Heap's Algorithm" ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm)) in Java, which constructs all permutations of a given set. (I am aware that this isn't technically Heap's algorithm because of subtleties pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46245677/heaps-algorithm-implementation-in-list-of-lists), but that's not terribly important to me currently).

What I have: I'm starting from a piece of code that works and does what I want:

```java
    public static <T> List<T[]> Permutations(T a[]) {
        LinkedList<T[]> list = new LinkedList<T[]>();
        heapPermutation(a, a.length, a.length, list);
        return list;
    }

    //Generating permutation using Heap Algorithm 
    public static <T> void heapPermutation(T a[], int size, int n, List<T[]> list) 
    { 
        // if size becomes 1 then adds the obtained 
        // permutation to the list
        if (size == 1) 
            list.add(a.clone());

        for (int i=0; i<size; i++) 
        { 
            heapPermutation(a, size-1, n, list); 

            // if size is odd, swap first and last 
            // element 
            if (size % 2 == 1) 
            { 
                T temp = a[0]; 
                a[0] = a[size-1]; 
                a[size-1] = temp; 
            } 

            // If size is even, swap ith and last 
            // element 
            else
            { 
                T temp = a[i]; 
                a[i] = a[size-1]; 
                a[size-1] = temp; 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Character[] chars = new Character[] {'a','b','c','d'};

        List<Character[]> list = Permutations(chars);
        for(Iterator<Character[]> i = list.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            Character[] array = i.next();
            for(int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                System.out.print(array[j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Again: This code works and outputs exactly what I want.

**Good Output:**

```
a b c d 
b a c d 
c a b d 
a c b d 
b c a d 
c b a d 
d b c a 
b d c a 
c d b a 
d c b a 
b c d a 
c b d a 
d a c b 
a d c b 
c d a b 
d c a b 
a c d b 
c a d b 
d a b c 
a d b c 
b d a c 
d b a c 
a b d c 
b a d c
```

**What I want:** I would like to replicate the above code, but to replace all instances of arrays with `List`s (or `ArrayList`s, `LinkedList`s, etc.).

**What I've tried:** Here is the modification I've attempted:

```java
   public static <T> List<List<T>> Permutations(List<T> a) {
        List<List<T>> list = new ArrayList<List<T>>();
        heapPermutation(a, a.size(), a.size(), list);
        return list;
    }

    //Generating permutation using Heap Algorithm 
    public static <T> void heapPermutation(List<T> a, int size, int n, List<List<T>> list) 
    { 
        List<T> aTemp = new ArrayList<T>(a);

        // if size becomes 1 then adds the obtained 
        // permutation to the list
        if (size == 1) {
            list.add(aTemp);
        }

        for (int i=0; i<size; i++) 
        { 
            heapPermutation(aTemp, size-1, n, list); 

            // if size is odd, swap first and last 
            // element 
            if (size % 2 == 1) 
            { 
                T temp = aTemp.get(0); 
                aTemp.set(0, a.get(size-1)); 
                aTemp.set(size-1,temp); 
            } 

            // If size is even, swap ith and last 
            // element 
            else
            { 
                T temp = aTemp.get(0); 
                aTemp.set(i, a.get(size-1));
                aTemp.set(size-1, temp);
            } 
        } 
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();
        list.add('a'); list.add('b'); list.add('c'); list.add('d');
        System.out.println(Permutations(list));
    }
```

However, unlike the first code block, this doesn't give what I want:

**Bad Output:**

```java
[[a, b, c, d], [b, a, c, d], [c, b, a, d], [b, c, a, d], [c, b, c, d], [b, c, c, d], [d, b, c, a], [b, d, c, a], [c, b, d, a], [b, c, d, a], [c, b, c, a], [b, c, c, a], [d, d, c, d], [d, d, c, d], [c, d, d, d], [d, c, d, d], [c, d, c, d], [d, c, c, d], [d, d, d, d], [d, d, d, d], [d, d, d, d], [d, d, d, d], [d, d, d, d], [d, d, d, d]]
```

What is going on in the second code block that makes it not correct? I'm 100% sure it's due to my lack of understanding of some subtleties of `List`s in Java, but I have no idea what's the culprit.

Before asking here, I tried the second block of code *without* adding `List<T> aTemp = new ArrayList<T>(a);`, and I've also tried tinkering with various parts of it to change instances of `a` to `aTemp` and vice versa. Nothing I've tried has worked.

### Edit 1

In a comment below, user @GPI pointed out a typo in my even case. After correcting `T temp = aTemp.get(0);` to `T temp = aTemp.get(i);`, I have the following output:

```java
[[a, b, c, d], [b, a, c, d], [c, b, a, d], [b, c, a, d], [c, b, c, d], [b, c, c, d], [d, b, c, a], [b, d, c, a], [c, b, d, a], [b, c, d, a], [c, b, c, a], [b, c, c, a], [d, d, c, b], [d, d, c, b], [c, d, d, b], [d, c, d, b], [c, d, c, b], [d, c, c, b], [d, d, d, c], [d, d, d, c], [d, d, d, c], [d, d, d, c], [d, d, d, c], [d, d, d, c]]
```

Note that this is also incorrect, because it contains a number of duplicates / lists which aren't actually permutations (such as `[d, d, d, c]`).

Comment: In the even case, `T temp = aTemp.get(0); ` should be `T temp = aTemp.get(i); `

Comment: @GPI - Thank you for your feedback! After implementing that change (which was very embarrassing), I'm still not getting the correct answer. I'll update to indicate.

Comment: Don't know about subtleties, but shouldn't `n` get used *somehow*?

Comment: the array variant adds an array clone just when `size == 1`, the List variant operates on a deep copy of `List<T> a`, mostly.

Comment: @greybeard - That's one of may confusions that I've encountered when finding snippets of code like these. My plan of action was to get a working implementation I'm happy with FIRST and _then_ try to do something about fixing the parts that seem extraneous.

Given that I can't even achieve functional correctness, I'm not going to muck with the `n`'s for now.

As for your second comment: Is the problem that I (a) don't implement an array clone in the `size!=1` cases, or (b) need to do something else entirely?

Comment: @greybeard - Essentially, what I mean to say is: I don't know enough about `List`s to know what to do to mimic the array functionality. Can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First, the typo

As already said, a first quick thing to fix is your typo : the even case should read `T temp = aTemp.get(i);`

### Second, the cloning

The crux of the matter is that you did not grasp how / when the list/array is modified in place, versus when it is copied over as a result to accumulate.

Without even looking at what your method is doing, we can see that the array version manipulates the array in place, except when its size is one in which case it is copied to the list of results.

In other words, in the array version, it always is the same array that has its items swapped, however deep the recursion goes.
Only when we want to remember a certain permutation of the items do we take a copy of it, to make sure the permutation is frozen (`a.clone()`), meaning we can still swap items after that without risking any modification of the already accumulated permutations.

The list version, on the other hand, copies its input each time it starts. In other words, at each recursion stage a local copy of the original list is used to swap items. When the recursion unrolls, the current arrangment of items of this copy is lost.

So if you remove the cloning of the list where it is, only keeping it inside the `if size == 1)` case, you should be OK.

In the end, it's not that there is a subtelty in the list case versus the ararys, just that you moved some "cloning" logic without analyzing the impact.

With that in place, the output becomes :

```
[[a, b, c, d], 
[b, a, c, d],
[c, a, b, d],
[a, c, b, d],
[b, c, a, d],
[c, b, a, d],
[d, b, c, a],
[b, d, c, a],
[c, d, b, a],
[d, c, b, a],
[b, c, d, a],
[c, b, d, a],
[d, a, c, b],
[a, d, c, b],
[c, d, a, b],
[d, c, a, b],
[a, c, d, b],
[c, a, d, b],
[d, a, b, c],
[a, d, b, c],
[b, d, a, c],
[d, b, a, c], 
[a, b, d, c],
[b, a, d, c]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! During the plethora of attempts I'd tried, I **THINK** I tried what you're syggesting first. I'll recheck again and follow up ASAP; my wife and I have to drive several hours away today for a chemotherapy infusion, though, so it may be later this evening.

Comment: I've updated with the output log so you may check. I respectfully address you and your family my best wishes.

Comment: Thanks for the well wishes! The infusion is happening now, so I've got five or so hours to burn. :) You were absolutely right about the duplication! In the beginning, I **did** only have one duplication (in the `size==1` case), but I **also** had the aforementioned typo. Fixing the typo + fixing the dumb cloning I did was perfect. Thanks again!